# Compress HTML with Node, Express & EJS?

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using EJS with Node and Express. The HTML produced by my views is large and full of unnecessary whitespace. Is there an option or middleware I can use in production that will compress the HTML?

E.g.,

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head><title>...</title>....</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your template engine should have a flag that you pass to it to compress it, I know that Jade does it by default (I haven't used EJS).

But I wouldn't bother with whitespace removal, instead I'd use a gzip library to gzip the response down, something like [gzippo](https://github.com/tomgco/gzippo) is what you're after.

Comment: I'll look into it. Yeah, I suppose this doesn't matter with gzip/run-length compression, but I'm still interested.